# data structure with STL I not understood how to declare

Tags: xcode

Your program should be able to achieve the following functions,
1- To add a new node to the bingeing, specific position, or the 2-
3-
4-
5- 6- 7- 8- 9- 10- 11-

To display List items.
To display List items in reverse order
To count the number of items
To insert a new item at the beginning
To insert a new item at the end
To insert a new item at the middle
To delete the first item
To delete an item from the middle
To delete the last item
To search an existing item and return node position

Comment: Welcome to SO, what you tried till now based on that we can help

Comment: From Review: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you haven't tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your existing code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, the syntax is pretty much straight forward when you need to do some sort of action with arrays.

Here are the examples that you were looking for.

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

// Insert a number to the beginning of the array
numbers.insert(0, at: 0)

// Append a number to the end of the array
numbers.append(11)

// Display the array of numbers in reverse order
print(numbers.reverse())

// Count the number of items in the array
numbers.count

// Remove the first item from the array
numbers.removeFirst()

// Remove the last item from the array
numbers.removeLast()

// Remove the item in the middle of the array (Only if the array count is not an even number so it has a middle value)
numbers.remove(at: (numbers.count / 2))

// Find the index of the number 3
numbers.firstIndex(of: 3)
```